# Why don't my php files work on my Apache2 server?

Tags: server, apache2, php, postgresql, xampp

I am trying to get a survey (PHP files) to work on an Apache server. I tried it first with XAMPP, but then got the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_escape_string() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/imageability/SkjemaDatabase.php on line 551
```

I tried a variety of solutions to this to get PostgreSQL to work together with XAMPP, but nothing seemed to work. So I have now decided to try installing PHP5, Apache2, PostgreSQL (and MYSQL) seperately. I followed [these](http://blog.keerthi.me/2009/04/ubuntu-installing-apache-php-mysql.html) instructions for the installations and thought I would have got PostgreSQL installed and working this time for sure. But instead of working, or rendering the same error message again, this just gives me a blank page when trying to check out the survey in Firefox. Am running Lubuntu 14.02 by the way.

I have some other PHP files on the server that work fine. Could it still be something about PostgreSQL that's not working? While trying out XAMPP I tried uncommenting the following lines in my php.ini file

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

But now (with the various software installed seperately) I actually can't find the lines at all in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` or `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`, but I'm not sure which file to look in.

I also read advise (during XAMPP problem with PostgreSQL) to copy the file `libpq.dll` from `c:/xampp/php/` to `/xampp/apache/bin/`, but I didn't seem to have this file and still don't.

Below are some other ideas about what might be wrong, but maybe the above are more plausible?

Another problem I had during the process was that while following the last instructions at the link above, I made the mistake of creating a super user with password and switching to postgres user. After this I couldn't open Pgadmin3, so I switched back to the usual user and then that at least worked. Could my error now have something to do with still having this superuser? Or is there something I have to do in Pgadmin3 to get my survey to work on the server? (I.e. I haven't done anything in Pgadmin3 now, just installed the above mentioned software and put my files in `/var/www/htlm/`.)

Very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I now found out the main problem was I didn't get any error messages.

To solve this, open the file `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` in a text editor as root. (In the terminal window, type the command `sudo emacs /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and press enter). 
Locate the line

```
display_errors = Off
```

and change it to

```
display_errors = On`
```

This helped me see that there was nothing wrong with PostgreSQL when using it with Apache2 installed separately (as opposed to when using XAMPP). See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/644399?noredirect=1) too, for more details on how to set up a developer environment on Debian/Ubuntu, to avoid having to use XAMPP if you wish to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried installing php5 on your ubuntu ?

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

then reconfigure the apache2 config file.

is your php service is running ?

Comment: I've installed php5, yes. PHP seems to be working too, yep. Reconfiguring the apache config file I'm not sure how to do though.