# Problems using PostgreSQL with XAMPP

Tags: server, php, postgresql, xampp

I seem to have trouble getting PostgreSQL to work on XAMPP (using Lubuntu 14.02). I am new to working with both PHP, servers and databases, but I get the following error message.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_escape_string() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/imageability/SkjemaDatabase.php on line 551

So it seems to me to be a problem with PostgreSQL. The same error message shows up for `pg_connect()`. I have tried a few things to get PostgreSQL to work with XAMPP, like uncommenting the following lines in my file `php.ini` and then restarting the server, without success.

> extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
>
> extension=php_pgsql.dll

I have also read you can try to copy the file `libpq.dll` to Apache folder, but I don't seem to have this file at all (searched with `find`). Can this be the problem?

I have also tried downloading Apache2, PHP5 and PostgreSQL seperately, but this doesn't seem to help me, as I in this case just get a blank page, without an error message even. The PHP files I am using are fine and working for other people and I can also get other PHP files to work on the server.

Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation: Don't use XAMPP for this! It's supposed to be a simple way to get the usual Apache, MySQL, PHP, +Python/Perl stack to work. Leave the walled garden and your pretty much on your own…

Also: Even if you *do* get it to work there is no guarantee that it won't break the next time your system or XAMPP itself. This use-case is not supported by anybody and some of the components involved (especially PHP) aren't designed to handle modules not compiled for their specific version.

## How to set up a developer environment natively on Debian/Ubuntu

1. Open a Terminal window (*Menu* → *Other* → *LXTerminal*)
2. Stop all XAMPP services currently running
3. Install the required packages:
   You may either use a GUI ("Software Center") for this or run this
   command on your Terminal:
   `sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-php5 postgresql php5-pgsql`

   - `apache2` (The Apache web server)
   - `libapache2-mod-php5` (PHP support for Apache)
   - `php5-pgsql` (PostgreSQL client support for PHP)
   - `postgresql` (The PostgreSQL server)
4. Open the file `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` in a text editor
   as root:
   In the Terminal window type the command
   `gksudo leafpad /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and press enter
5. Locate the line `display_errors = Off` and change it to
   `display_errors = On`
   [image: Screenshot of the display_errors line and documentation]
6. Save the file and close the editor
7. Restart the Apache web server:
   Run the command `sudo service apache2 restart` in your Terminal
   window to restart the web server and reload its PHP module

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark as accepted answer if this helped you! Do ask for clarification if something doesn't make sense to you!

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! The error display was just what I needed! Turned out it wasn't PostgreSQL that was the problem when using Apache2 + PostgreSQL (although it was in XAMPP), but I would never have worked it out without error messages. Now there are just minor (hopefully) things I need to see to before I can get everything up and running, like getting my PostgreSQL server hosted somewhere. Thanks again!